# Why can't I access state when setting it in useEffect React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When component renders I send a socket emit with socket io to get data inside useEffect, I also listen to get the data. When i get the data back from socket I update state then call a function. Inside the fuction the state is empty. Why is state empty?

```
const [chatData, setChatData] = useState([]);

const handleData = () => {
console.log(chatData)
}

useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("chatData");

    socket.on("chatData", (data) => {
    setChatData(data)
    handleData();
    });

    return () => {
      socket.off("chatData");
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Setting state is an async process so use another `useEffect` that checks for changes in state: `useEffect(() => handleData(), [chatData]);`

Comment: That works I appreciate that, Question can I use async await inside useEffect so await setting state then calling function? Instead of using multiple useEffects. Thanks!

Comment: `setState` (or whatever you call it) maybe an async process but it doesn't return a promise so you can't `await` it.

Answer (score 2):

In this case React cannot promise you it will update the state immediately. However, you can pass a functions to `setChatData` for setting the data (in which you can call your function) instead of the value.
For example:

```js
socket.on("chatData", (data) => {
    setChatData(() => {
        handleData(data);
        return data;
    };
});
```

Or as someone said in the comments you can use another `useEffect` hook with `chatData` as a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `useMemo` or `useEffect` to detect new status changes. Therefore, if you need to run a function after changing the state and prevent the repeated execution of a program, I recommend this.

In this case you don't need `handleData`. So you can use other useEffect for detect changes. Like this:

```
const [chatData, setChatData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
console.log(chatData)
},[chatData])

useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("chatData");

    socket.on("chatData", (data) => {
    setChatData(data)
    });

    return () => {
      socket.off("chatData");
    };
  }, []);
```